# Take mean of column from dataframe that consist of arrays

Tags: python, dataframe, nan, mean

I'm trying to take mean of each column in a dataframe that consists of arrays `[x,y,z]`. Moreover, the arrays can be filled with NaN values `[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan].` I tried this:

```
np.mean([df[col].mean() for col in df.columns], axis=0)
```

But this did not work :/
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: It might be better to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the arrays into single value cells.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'score1':[2010,np.nan,2010,2011,2011,2011],
'score2':[1,2,np.nan,1,2,3],
'score3':[np.nan,np.nan,32,14,15,16]})

print([df[col].mean() for col in df.columns])
```

Output

```
[2010.6, 1.8, 19.25]
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to accomplish. But instead of ex.   'year'[2010,np.nan,2010,2011,2011,2011] I have 'year'[array[nan,nan,nan],array[12,10,8],array[nan,nan,nan] etc.]

Comment: It would be clearer if you could show your example in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataframe looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"foobar":["foo", "bar", "baz"], 
        "year":[[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 
                [12,10,8], 
                [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
  foobar             year
0    foo  [nan, nan, nan]
1    bar      [12, 10, 8]
2    baz  [nan, nan, nan]
```

...you can build a new column with the mean values by using `apply`:

```
df["means"] = df.year.apply(np.mean)
result_list = df.means.values # array([nan, 10., nan])
```

```
  foobar             year  means
0    foo  [nan, nan, nan]    NaN
1    bar      [12, 10, 8]   10.0
2    baz  [nan, nan, nan]    NaN
```

**However**, depending on what else you want to do with your data, it might be better to `explode` the sequences into single cells to get a much more *pandaesque* structure:

```
df = df.explode(column="year")
df["year"] = df.year.astype(float) # tell Pandas it's numerical data
```

```
  foobar  year
0    foo   NaN
0    foo   NaN
0    foo   NaN
1    bar  12.0
...
```

Now just use default operations to get the values grouped by `foobar` or whatever your column name is.

```
mean_df = df.groupby("foobar").mean()
```

```
         year
foobar      
bar     10.0
baz      NaN
foo      NaN
```